# Prolog Factorial using recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, factorial

I can't seem to wrap my head around how this works, to be specific I don't understand how F1 represents the value of (N-1)! cause the way I see it once we reach the base case the value of F1 stays at 1 seeing as to how it is never reassigned. I just want to understand for instance if `N = 4`, how once we reach the base case the value of F1 goes from 1 to 2 to 6.

```
factorial(0,1).   

factorial(N,F) :-    
   N>0,   
   N1 is N-1,   
   factorial(N1,F1),   
   F is N * F1.
```

Comment: Try using gtrace with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Prolog's inference engine does that for us, happily. Seen with e.g. `gtrace` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *the value* of F1 stays at 1

> how *the value* of F1

The secret is that you need plural not singular; when running your code, Prolog makes many variables named `F1`, one for each intermediate value. Each call to `factorial(N1, F1)` adds a new layer to the *call stack*, with a new copy of all the variables which `factorial/2` uses. They have the same names, but they are separate in memory and can be bound to different values.

This is the same stack which can grow too big in unbounded recursion and overflow, giving a stackoverflow error, the name of this website.

```
F    is 4 * F1_a
F1_a is 3 * F1_b
F1_b is 2 * F1_c
F1_c is 1 * F1_d
F1_d = 1
```

The stack is built up in memory, then when the base case is reached the code can move on to `F is N * F1.` and the stack collapses down and the intermediate `F1`s are cleared out.

Comment: The hardest connection for me to make was that the value of `F` is actually the value of `F1` in an initially called `factorial(N1, F1)`, hence when `F` is assigned `F1` gets consecutively assigned in the previous predicate . And this is how the value of `F1` is "remembered", your explanation really cleared that bit up, thanks a lot.